# Output Checkboxes From Nested Array

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, vuejs2

Within my data I have multiple items, each with a nested category array containing an **ID** and **name**. Ex:

```
    {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Title Five",
    "notes": "-",
    "category-data": [
        [
            {
                "cat-id": 2,
                "cat-name": "Category Two"
            }
        ]
    ]
},
```

How can I loop over each data item to output the name from **category-data** avoiding duplicates?

I am unsure as to how to loop over and output the nested **category-data** items.

**Edit: I had to slightly change my data structure to:**

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title one",
    "category_data": {
        "1": "Category One Name",
        "2": "Category Two Name"
    }
},
```

Cheers

Comment: Just to be sure: Your category-data has a *list of lists* of categories, and you want to basically iterate over all of them and get a single, unique list of them?

Comment: Hi, for each item "Title Five", output the checkbox "Category Two".

Comment: I think you'll need to update your question to be more clear of what you're trying to do, maybe with an example, because as-is it isn't clear at all.

Comment: Ok, will do. Essentially, I want to output a list of checkboxes  for each of the cat-names.

Comment: @David.J you want only the 3 categories with `cat-name` key?

Comment: if `Object.title` is unique, probably [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxREPW?editors=1011) meets your requirements.

Comment: @Sphinx that's almost perfect. The checkboxes should be the cat names though, not the title. Cheers

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I want all the categories output as checkboxes, without duplicates. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After my data structure was improved, I could loop through it as expected.

```
 <div v-for="(item, index) in info" :key="index" class="form-check">
    <div v-for="(category, index) in item.category_data" :key="index">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" v-model="cat_data" :id="index" :value="index">
        <label class="form-check-label">{{ category }}</label>
    </div>
 </div>
```